# C - Cmake compiling program with libcurl

Tags: c, curl, compiler-errors, libcurl, clion

I'm trying to use some curl code to test the lib but I can't compile it :(

I'm using Clion (Cmake + gcc) and I've got a libcurl.a, a libcurl.dll and a libcurl.dlla
What am I suppose to do with those 3 files ?

This is my CmakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(curl_test2 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

ADD_DEFINITIONS( -DCURL_STATICLIB )
include_directories( "include" )

set(SRCS"
srcs/main.c")
set(HEADERS
    "include/curl/curl.h"
     "include/curl/easy.h")

link_directories("lib")

add_executable(curl_test2 ${SRCS} ${HEADERS})

target_link_libraries(curl_test2 "curl")
```

this is my project:

```
include
    --curl
        --curl.h
srcs
    --main.c
lib
    --libcurl.a
    (--dlls
        --libcurl.dll
        --libcurl.dlla) <- i'm not using them for now
```

this is my main.c (just a libcurl example, not really important - i'm just trying to compile):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "curl/curl.h"

int main(void)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://postit.example.com/moo.cgi");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "name=daniel&project=curl");

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                    curl_easy_strerror(res));

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

When I'm trying to build the compiler drop this error : "undefined reference to `_imp__curl_global_init'" (and all other curl function calls)

Can you help me ? I'm a bit lost - I did not really use Cmake before..

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You link with static curl library (libcurl.a) which required CURL_STATICLIB definition. Add this in your CMakeLists.txt between "project" and "add_executable" commands:

```
add_definitions( -DCURL_STATICLIB )
```

Moreover, your file .dlla is not .dll.a ? In that case, .dll.a file is (I think) generated by MinGW toolchain and is required only if you link dynamically with curl library (as .dll file).

I downloaded the sources of cURL library [here](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html) and compiled it (with Visual Compiler 2015). It produces shared libraries (`libcurl.dll` and `libcurl_imp.lib`) that I move in the lib directory (I should rename `libcurl_imp.lib` to `curl.lib`). I move also the include directory.

Then, I used this `CMakeLists.txt` :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(curl_test2 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

set(SRCS "srcs/main.c")

set( CURL_LIBRARY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib )
set( CURL_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include )
find_package( CURL )

include_directories( ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
link_directories( ${CURL_LIBRARIES} )

add_executable(curl_test2 ${SRCS})
target_link_libraries(curl_test2 curl)
```

With it, your project compiles and the execution works.

I also tried with cURL static library (for that, if you use CMake to compile cURL, add `-DCURL_STATICLIB=ON` in cmake command line). And I moved the produced library `libcurl.lib` to `lib\curl.lib`.

I used this `CMakeLists.txt` :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(curl_test2 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

set(SRCS "srcs/main.c")
add_definitions( -DCURL_STATICLIB )

set( CURL_LIBRARY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib )
set( CURL_INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include )
find_package( CURL )

include_directories( ${CURL_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
link_directories( ${CURL_LIBRARIES} )

add_executable(curl_test2 ${SRCS})
target_link_libraries(curl_test2 curl wldap32 ws2_32)
```

And it works too.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer !
Cmake drop me this : Unknown CMake command "add_denifition".

My file is .dll.a, my bad 

Also, I don't really get why, but i added the include_directories command and my .c won't compile with the new relative path..

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the ending "s"  in the command "add_definition**s**"
I corrected it.
For include directories, do you delete your CMake cache before ?

Comment: I don't know how to delete the Cmake cache. Delete the cmakecache.txt file ?
I still have the "undefined reference to `curl_global_init'" .. :(

Comment: If you execute CMake elsewhere than the source directory (and I hope you do), like a "build" directory for exemple, remove the cache :
* with CMake GUI : File > Delete Cache
* with command line : rm -rf build/*

Comment: Ok the include works, thanks.
But I still have the "undefined reference to `curl_global_init'" .. :(

Comment: I try with cURL shared Library and it works. Is it enough for you or do you need use only static library ?

Comment: I can use the the shared library too. How did you linked with it ? I think I tried it 2 weeks ago but it failed (or most obviously: I failed :s )

Comment: You need `libcurl.dll` and `curl.lib` in the directory `lib` during the compilation. And `libcurl.dll` is alose required in the execution path or in the PATH environment variable.

Comment: I advise you to compile your project and the cURL library with the same compiler. I don't observe your problem of "undefined reference to ..." which show your compiler can't read correctly your cURL library. I think it could be corrected by using the same compiler from the beginning to the end.